# Codeigniter undefined property on controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, controller

i have controller to show database record on table

```
function gkategorimaterial()
{
    $this->load->model('m_kategorimaterial');
    $data['kirim'] = $this->m_kategorimaterial->read(); //error pointing on this line
    $data['title'] = 'QB Ambil Kategori Material / Jasa';

    $this->load->view('head',$data);
    $this->load->view('g/gkategorimaterial',$data);
}
```

that `gkategorimaterial()` was adapted from

```
function vkategorimaterial()
{
    $this->load->model('m_kategorimaterial');

    $data['kirim'] = $this->m_kategorimaterial->read();
    $data['title'] = 'QB Kategori Material';

    $this->load->view('head',$data);
    $this->load->view('v/vkategorimaterial',$data);
}
```

which has the some function, to show the table, the `vkategorimaterial()` success to retrieve the record.

here is the model of `m_kategorimaterial

```
function read()
{
    $query = $this->db->order_by('Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa','DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material');

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {     
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: C_materialjasa::$m_kategorimaterial

Filename: controllers/c_materialjasa.php

Line Number: 140

i believe it has nothing to do with the models, but i don't know what the error is, since i just copy paste the first controller which is `vkategorimaterial()` controller, and rename the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are database loaded on m_kategorimaterial?

```
$this->load->database();
```

or set in ./application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Or try add parent in controller:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Loading a model:

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('Model_name');
```

Model ('models/Model_name.php')

```
class Model_name extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    }

        function read() { return; }
}
```

Make sure that is model file CHMOD-ed to 0755!

Comment: yes i did, i have loaded the database record successfully before. and i don't know why i can't load this one :(

Comment: Try add parent in a controller, and try add auto-connect on model: You can tell the model loading function to auto-connect by passing TRUE (boolean) via the third parameter, and connectivity settings, as defined in your database config file will be used: $this->load->model('Model_name', '', TRUE);

Comment: okay i'll do it, btw is there anything wrong with the controller ?

Comment: FYI, i have commented on `$this->load->view()` line, and try this `print_r($this->m_kategorimaterial->read());` it shows the same error, it says `Message: Undefined property: C_materialjasa::$m_kategorimaterial`

Comment: This sounds can't call model. Are you sure that is controller loaded a model?

Comment: yes i want that `gkategorimaterial()` controller, load the `read()` model, then pass them into the table views

Answer (score 0):

my bad ! i wrote class `classname` extends CI_Controller on the model file

Comment: I advice you to do basic debugging before you run here. In previous question too i saw that your question contained mistakes which can only be attributed to lack of attention and concentration. Anyways, you can ask a limited number of questions within a month. Don't run out on that.